# Java Mail api, copy message sucessfully but email deleted from exchange server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Using java mail api, we monitor a the Inbox folder and process emails. If an error occurs while processing an email, we move it to an error folder.

If that is successful we delete the email from the inbox folder. Following is a snippet of mail debugging. It shows the copy as successful, but the email is never found in the error directory and its also deleted from inbox.

Why would this happen? Also why would java mail api report a success even though the mail is not copied.

```
2013-10-04 14:25:20,886 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] monitor.EmailMonitor monitor.EmailMonitor (EmailMonitor.java:393) - Copy error message to error folder
2013-10-04 14:25:20,889 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] STDOUT util.LoggerStream (LoggerStream.java:156) - A10 COPY 1 Inbox/error
2013-10-04 14:25:20,896 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] STDOUT util.LoggerStream (LoggerStream.java:156) - A10 OK COPY completed.
2013-10-04 14:25:20,897 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] monitor.EmailMonitor monitor.EmailMonitor (EmailMonitor.java:400) - Mark message as deleted from monitored folder
2013-10-04 14:25:20,897 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] STDOUT util.LoggerStream (LoggerStream.java:156) - A11 STORE 1 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
2013-10-04 14:25:20,907 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] STDOUT util.LoggerStream (LoggerStream.java:156) - * 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted \Recent))
A11 OK STORE completed.
2013-10-04 14:25:20,907 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] monitor.EmailMonitor monitor.EmailMonitor (EmailMonitor.java:404) - Expunge the monitored folder
2013-10-04 14:25:20,908 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] STDOUT util.LoggerStream (LoggerStream.java:156) - A12 EXPUNGE
2013-10-04 14:25:20,922 [] [] [] INFO  [monitorScheduler-1] STDOUT util.LoggerStream (LoggerStream.java:156) - * 1 EXPUNGE
* 0 EXISTS
A12 OK EXPUNGE completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your server that's reporting success.

Try using a different name for the error folder, not something named under Inbox, in case that helps.